# Add a custom file extension to Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

I am trying to figure out how to add a custom file type to be recognised by Netbeans.

I am editing .tpl files and I would like them to be recognised as PHP/HTML files.

I've looked [here](http://www.techienuggets.com/Comments?tx=38126) and [here](http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic3275.html) but I cant find cnd.properties in config directory and there is no `Advanced Options` dialog in the options dialog.

I'm using Netbeans 6.5 with PHP and all modules up to date.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Let me guess, for Smarty templates? I did the following

1. Open Tools and Select Options.
2. Select Miscellaneous tab.
3. Select Files sub-tab thing.
4. Click on **New** file extension and enter **tpl**.
5. Select the mime type.
6. Click OK. Done!
7. (Restart of Netbeans may be required to see the actual changes)

Comment: I don't have a files tab on my netbeans 6.0.1 (upgrading isn't an option for this project). Is there an alternative? (don't know if it's relevant but I use it on ubuntu8)

Comment: Still relevant but: I'd like to use extension with a dot (like "somefile.css.php") and it won't let me save if there is a dot in the extensions :(

Comment: Is this possible per project, too? Maybe even in a way that it is attached to the file or project? In the sense: when I commit this configuration change to the source repository other team members will benefit from it?

Comment: there is better match "text/x-php5" compared to tpl which is a generic template for html

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. The editor treats tpl files still as "all files", not as "html files" (I set 2 space indentation for html and 4 space indentation for all files, and Source/Format reformats my TPLs still with 4 spaces, not two. Any suggestions what I might do wrong?

Comment: Did it for me with .md files from revealjs. Very helpful!

Comment: on netbeans version 20 it allowed me to add cjs file extension as javascript.

Answer (score 6):

In NetBeans 8.XX this is achieved by going to **NetBeans > Preferences > Miscellaneous > Files**. In the row **File Extension** click on **NEW** and enter your new file extension without the dot (example: *tpl*). Choose the **Associated File Type (MIME)** and click **Apply**.

Answer (score 4):

Go to

```
Netbeans
    tools
     options
      Miscellaneous
        Files
```

Now find the row `file extension` select `tpl` . Then **most important** to Choose the `Associated File Type (MIME)` as `text/x-php5`. After save this, restart netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for how to get Netbeans to recognize smarty templates, there's now a Smarty template plugin that should be more useful:
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/37379/php-smarty

Comment: This dates back to 2011 and is made for Netbeans 7.0.