# Netbean PHP formatting stopped work

Tags: netbeans

I have started work with netbean 8.0 (beta), Suddenly only the php formatting stopped work.
Did someone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like  <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: That I know... It worked, but suddenly it stopped work... by the way it still works on js document.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was that i used file with the extension of module...(Drupal)
[And that was the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905416/add-a-custom-file-extension-to-netbeans)