# How do I get Netbeans to recognise the php code inside my css stylesheets?

Tags: php, css, netbeans

I am echoing php variables, mostly, into a stylesheet. What I would like to do is have netbeans recognise the php code as php code and highlight the syntax as such.

Is there a config file somewhere that I can add *.css to, which will run the php syntax highlighter/formatter on said stylesheet?

Thanx for any help!

Comment: [How do i run PHP inside CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367134/how-do-i-run-php-inside-css) (Maybe using .php file extension (?))

Comment: You should use .php extension

Comment: Maybe like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905416/add-a-custom-file-extension-to-netbeans Not sure, though; I don't have Netbeans any more.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001660/is-there-a-way-to-mix-css-and-php/46001762#46001762 it works for me with NetBeans